# How do I reference inside of a Python dictionary's dictionary?

Tags: python, json

> This post has been resolved

How do I reference the `topic` key in the questions?
I'd like to search my list for all questions that have a specific topic and then return all of the information about a random question.

However, when using the code below, I get an error saying that:

```
    if question['topic'] == topic:
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

However, if I try changing the integers to strings, I get an error saying that they must be integers. How do I solve this?

Code - This code is supposed to add all of the questions of a specific topic to a list so that I can use a random function inside of the list to generate the random question.

```py
def random_question_in_topic(topic: str):
    topic_questions = []
    for question in questions:
        if question['topic'] == topic:
            topic_questions.append(question)
    
    print(topic_questions)
```

Extract from my dictionary.(Total of 30 items)

```py
questions = {
    1 : {
        'type': 'memory',
        "topic": "literature",
        "question": "Who wrote Twilight series of novels?",
        "answer": "stephenie meyer",
    },
    2 : {
        'type': 'memory',
        "topic": "literature",
        "question": "What was Frankenstein's first name?",
        "answer": "jolly roger",
    },
    3 : {
        'type': 'memory',
        "topic": "general",
        "question": "What is the only anagram of the word 'english'?",
        "answer": "shingles",
    },
    4 : {
        'type': 'memory',
        "topic": "general",
        "question": "Gala, Jonagold and Pink Lady are varieties of which fruit?",
        "answer": "apple",
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

I'm using Python 3.8.12 on Replit.

Comment: Iterating over a dict iterates over keys, not values.

Comment: It really seems like `questions` should be a list not a dictionary. Then you could directly pull a random dict from the list.

Comment: Try: `for question in questions:.values():` to loop over the values which are dictionaries.

Comment: My use is an API, so I'm returning it as a JSON object.

Comment: `for question in questions.values()`

Comment: The consumers of the api would probably prefer a list as well. JSON has no trouble representing lists.

Comment: Thanks everyone. It's working now. Also, the consumers will only be getting one object.

Comment: On Stack Overflow it not a habit to put any kind of tags into the title. Choose the most helpful answer as soon as you are allowed to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
for question in questions.values():
        if question['topic'] == 'history':
            print(question)
            topic_questions.append(question)
```

Thank you commentors on the original post.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs since when you iterate over a dictionary, you are iterating over its keys. Let's look at it closely.

If you run the following code

```
for question in questions:
    print(question)
```

...you will get the following output:

```
1
2
3
4
```

So, instead of iterating over keys, you might want to iterate over the values of the dictionary instead. For this purpose you may use the `values()` method of `dict` object. So, if you try the following code:

```
for question in questions.values():
    print(question)
```

...you will get the output as:

```
{'type': 'memory', 'topic': 'literature', 'question': 'Who wrote Twilight series of novels?', 'answer': 'stephenie meyer'}
...
```

Now, the variable `question` is an object which you can use indexing upon, like, `question['topic']`. So, the code could be re-written as:

```
def random_question_in_topic(topic: str):
    topic_questions = []
    for question in questions.values():
        if question['topic'] == topic:
            topic_questions.append(question)
    
    print(topic_questions)
```